# Jquery text field updating within foreach Razor

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, foreach

I am working on a simple asp.net razor display page, where I get my data trough the ViewBag. Within the data, there is a supplier id, but I want to display the supplier name.
The html:

```
@foreach (XXX supplier in ViewBag.UnApprovedOrders)
{
<tr >
   <td>
      <text id="supplierName">na</text>
      <script>supplierFromId("@supplier.SupplierId");</script>
   </td>
</tr>
```

and the script:

```
function supplierFromId(supplierId)
{
var name;
for (var i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
   if (list[i].id == supplierId) name = list[i].name;
}
   $("#supplierName").text(name);
};
```

The list is the suppliers list provided from elsewhere.
The question is: the function is called only once, so only the first field gets the correct name, the rest remains "na". 
What is wrong?

Comment: Why not do this in the code and return a model that already contains the supplier name, then your razor only needs to display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
@foreach (XXX supplier in ViewBag.UnApprovedOrders)
{
<tr >
   <td>
      <text class="supplierName">@supplier.SupplierId</text>
   </td>
</tr>
}

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.supplierName').each(function() {

        var supplierId = $(this).text();
        var name = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
           if (list[i].id == supplierId) name = list[i].name;
        }

        $(this).text(name)
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is nearly working, except the function is not called (just placed a console.log("supplierId"); and nothing displayed. Also the fields displaying the numerical values, because of the previous reason.

Comment: changing the val() to text() does the trick. Thank you for everyone! :)

Answer (score 2):

The `id` you specify `<text id="supplierName">na</text>` will be duplicated because of your foreach loop.

My suggestion is to change from using `id` to using `class` to identify the suppliernames. Then you can use jquery's  [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to update all with the class name.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: @Paxsentry the .each is a link to the documentation of the function

Answer (score 2):

An ID is specifically identifying a single element. Using a class should make this work. Classes are designed to be used on multiple elements and will allow you to update all of your  elements

Answer (score 2):

`<text id="supplierName">na</text>`

You are creating many tag within id `supplierName`, but only the first tag can be applied.

To fix this, try to convert `id` to `class`, like this:

`<text class="supplierName">na</text>`

```
<script>
$(".supplierName").each(function() {
   // do something...
});
</script>
```